# Questions about the channel creation process

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-go

I have an API with an endpoint creating a channel, joining a peer to it and instantiating chaincodes on it. While coding the process I encountered some interrogations about how things are done.

- An organization admin certificate is [tested byte per byte](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/blob/master/internal/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/msp/mspimpl.go#L468) while other roles use OUs. **Do we have an explication to why the admin verification behaves this way?**
- I could never manage to enroll and submit the exact same certificate for an organization admin. Due to the above problem, it means that the only solution I found to be able to perform admin operations was to copy the admin cert/key to the sdk crypto-{msp,store}. **Is there a way to avoid doing the copy of the admin certificate and private key using fabric-ca?**
- I could not manage to instantiate a chaincode on a newly created channel without having an entry for it in the sdk config file due to the fact that the sdk does not find any channelPeer for it. **Is there a way to avoid the config file update if we can programmatically know which peer has the channel?**

If anyone has an hint on how to solve any of the above question I would appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the discovery service can be useful for the third bullet question.
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/discovery-overview.html

Comment: Hi @LeonardoCarraro, apologies for the delay.. Sadly, even if the discovery service is enabled and used, the chaincode requests made by the fabric-go-sdk seem to only care about the configuration file..